# Variables that Improve SLAM

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, autonomous-car

I have a general question regarding SLAM as I am not an expert on the topic. What are the variables that can improve map generation?

The ones I can think of are:

1. A higher resolution camera
2. Consistent lighting conditions
3. A room with plenty of high confidence landmarks
4. A lot of processing power on the robot

Could someone help elaborate this list for me or tell me if I'm completely wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you are restricted to camera-only SLAM you are on a good track. You mentioned a robot, do you use its odometry?

- How good is your extrinsic robot-camera calibration?
- How good is your intrinsic camera calibration?
- Could you add a better IMU?
- Could you improve the Odometry by changing the wheels or the floor?
- Can you add other sensors like a laserscanner?
- Does your camera have a rolling shutter or global shutter?
- Do you exactly know when the image acquisition was started (e.g. because it was triggered by a hardware trigger?)
- Which opening angle does your camera have? (bigger would be better if you can handle lens distortion)
- Can you add artificial landmarks (e.g. QR-Marker) in the scene?

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is in generall so the answers will be, too. What is your application? It is in Indoor or Outdoor? Do you have a specific SLAM in you mind to use?
However, in general, I propose you do not limit your self to monocular cameras. If you are in an indoor environment I propose you RGBD cameras and in an outdoor environment, stereo cameras would be a better fit. Aso do not forget to calibrate your camera, see these two link for calibrating the camera by [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) and [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration).
The next stepps will be odometry fusion. Using IMU, wheel encoders, LIDAR, Sonar and so on will be helpful. The [robot pose EKF](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) can help you with odometry fusion.